# Dropdown removing the leading zeros in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, dropdownbox

I have a database in MS Access with one table field named "Seat number" with the text data type having entries 001, 002........100, 62AB.  While populating the values, there were no issues but when I try to select seat numbers having leading zeros (e.g. 001,002,009,010 etc.) by doing

`string seatList =(ddlSeatList.SelectedValue.ToString());`

it removes the leading zero(es).

Comment: Since it's already Text, do you need the `ToString()` method?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have up to three digits in seat you can use

```
string seatList =(ddlSeatList.SelectedValue.ToString("000"));
```

**UPDATE:**

Solutions above is completely wrong.
Based on comments dropdown list is initialized in the following way

```
if (seatselection=="9F") 
{ 
  seatalloaction = ("select TCS_Seat_ID,TCS_Seat_Num from TCS_Seat where TCS_Seat_Enable_F=" + "'Y'");
} 
DataSet dataTCSSeat = new DataSet(); 
dataTCSSeat = drpDownList.ExecuteQuery(seatalloaction);
ddlSeatList.Items.Add(new ListItem("TCS_Seat_ID", "TCS_Seat_Num")); 
if (dataTCSSeat.Tables.Count > 0) 
{ 
  for (int i = 0; i < dataTCSSeat.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++) 
  {
    ddlSeatList.Items.Add(new ListItem(
      dataTCSSeat.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString(),
      dataTCSSeat.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString())); 
  }
}
```

Thus *ddlSeatList.SelectedValue* returns values from _TCS_Seat_ID_ field, not from _TCS_Seat_Num_ as visualized. If it is required to get exacly the value from dropdown as it is shown in list control must be initialized in the following way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataTCSSeat.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++) 
{
  //both text and value are initialized with TCS_Seat_Num field values
  ddlSeatList.Items.Add(new ListItem(
    dataTCSSeat.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString(),
    dataTCSSeat.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString())); 
}
```

Comment: After selecting the dropdown seat number i am blocking  that seat it  won't be available to next user so an udpate query with a flag variable name X 
string seatList =(ddlSeatList.SelectedValue.ToString());
string  sEATUSED = ("UPDATE TCS_Seat SET TCS_Seat_Enable_F=" + "'X'" + "WHERE TCS_Seat_Num=" + Convert.ToString(seatList) );

Now if my seat number assuem it is 62A ,or some alpha numerical how will i get it block in seat table

Comment: Getting Error if i used ToString("000")); Error 32 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider' C:\Users\as03115\Desktop\PowaiAssociate\AddNewAsoociate.aspx.cs 263 72 C:\...\PowaiAssociate\ 

and 2nd error

Error 31 The best overloaded method match for 'string.ToString(System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\as03115\Desktop\PowaiAssociate\AddNewAsoociate.aspx.cs 263 37 C:\...\PowaiAssociate\

Comment: I have not noticed your field is text and not nummeric.

Do I understand your problem right that  you have data biding of dataset to your combobox with both DisplayMember and ValueMember specified as the same text field but you get nummeric-like text values loosing their leading zeros. Is it correct?

Comment: absloutely correct YES sir it is not numeric while selecting the value from dropdown it is removing the leading ZERO as i can see the value in variable  while debugging

Comment: Could you please confirm that you have ddlSeatList.DataTextField and ddlSeatList.DataValueField set to the same "Seat number" field and are assigned prior to assigning DataSource property? I see that you're using ASP controls, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes i am using asp controls Here is code ion select index change of prior dropdon i am populating the seat dropdown from database as it is

Comment: if (seatselection=="9F")
{
seatalloaction = ("select TCS_Seat_ID,TCS_Seat_Num from TCS_Seat where TCS_Seat_Enable_F=" + "'Y'");}
DataSet dataTCSSeat = new DataSet();
dataTCSSeat = drpDownList.ExecuteQuery(seatalloaction);
ddlSeatList.Items.Add(new ListItem("TCS_Seat_ID", "TCS_Seat_Num"));
 if (dataTCSSeat.Tables.Count > 0)
 {
 for (int i = 0; i < dataTCSSeat.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{ 
ddlSeatList.Items.Add(new ListItem(dataTCSSeat.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString(), dataTCSSeat.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString()));
  }
Plese ignore all the bracket might be less

Comment: if you see teh last line there i am assigning it

{ ddlSeatList.Items.Add(new ListItem(dataTCSSeat.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString(), dataTCSSeat.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString())); }

Comment: Is it not the reason of problems that you specify TCS_Seat_Num as text and TCS_Seat_ID as value? I suspect that TCS_Seat_ID is numeric and is 1 for '001', 10 for '010' etc. 
Should you not either use both TCS_Seat_Num in both cases (ddlSeatList.Items.Add(new ListItem("TCS_Seat_Num", "TCS_Seat_Num"));) or change your query "WHERE **TCS_Seat_ID**=" + Convert.ToString(seatList));?

Comment: probelm is not here actually when i selected the seatList there only it is removing
  string seatList = (ddlSeatList.SelectedValue.ToString());

Comment: Normally ddlSeatList.SelectedValue returns value of ListItem, not text but shows text naturally. As a result if you specify value to be different from text you'll see one string in dropdown but get completely another as SelectedValue

Comment: I transfered hard to read code from comments to answer. Please let me know if it helps